# Prevent clicks to pass through in UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Suppose I have a tableview cell.

On this I have an UIVIew rating control which works by adding buttons as subviews.

When the user clicks besides the buttons, but still on the rating control, the click is passed through to the underlying cell. I do not want that.

I am thinking there must be a proper way inside the rating control code (derived from UIView) to catch all clicks passed to it and simply never pass them through any further to the cell.

Comment: Did you try `tableView.allowsSelection = false`?

Comment: I need other areas of the cell to behave regularly. I just need the rating control grab all clicks in its area (and those clicks that are on raingcontrol buttons should of course belong to the buttons) As it is now, it appears clicks ouside the buttons but within the ratingcontrol is passed through to the cell underneath

Comment: Show your code and UI.